# How to parse multiple contacts from vcard using php and store into array

Tags: php

I have a vcard file with multiple contacts:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
N:Smith;Jim;Alvin;Mr.
FN:Jim A. Smith
CATEGORIES:Family
BDAY:1977-01-27
ADR;WORK:;Suite 900;11 5th Street;Coco Beach;FL;32082
ADR;HOME:;;198 Elm Street;Coco Beach;FL;32082
TEL;WORK:904-555-9384;
TEL;HOME:904-873-0394
TEL;CELL:904-934-3429
END:VCARD

BEGIN:VCARD
N:Barnes;Julie
FN:Julie Barnes
CATEGORIES:Business
ADR:;Suite 520;177 Bovet Road;San Mateo;CA;94402
TEL;WORK:650-573-3215
TEL;FAX:650-573-3244
EMAIL;INTERNET:jbarnes@virage.com
TITLE:Business Development Manager
ORG:Virage, Inc.
END:VCARD

BEGIN:VCARD
N:Barnes & Nobel
FN:Barnes & Nobel
CATEGORIES:Business
TEL;PREF:410-203-9001
END:VCARD
```

When I am parsing this vcard file with a single contact it works fine. 
The problem is parsing a vcard with multiple contacts.

Comment: Edit your question and put working code of single contact.

Comment: Why do you have codeigniter tags, are they related to your question?

Comment: Please include the code you've tried, and the errors you're getting.